# Sub report displaying all records

Tags: ms-access

I having trouble with sub reports showing all available records when I need them to only display those appropriate to the current record of the main report.

I am using Microsoft Access 2016

Comment: Please have a look in [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give more information.

Comment: How are you master/child links set up?

Comment: Have you even set the Master/Child Links properties of subform container?